# PHP Warning: implode()

Tags: php, arguments, implode

I'm getting the error below... HP Warning:  implode() [function.implode]: Argument must be an array

```
if (!empty($_FILES) && in_array('adjunto', array_keys($_FILES) ) ) {
    $mail->AddAttachment( $_FILES['adjunto']['tmp_name'],$_FILES['adjunto']['name'] );        
}               
error_log(" Files ".implode("",array_keys($_FILES)).' '.implode( array_keys($_FILES['adjunto']) ).date('Y/m/d H:i:s')."\n",3,"./adjuntos/log.log");
$mail->Send();
```

Comment: @Jeff `implode()` can be called with one argument, it's the array and the delimiter defaults to an empty string.

Comment: FYI, `in_array('adjunto', array_keys($_FILES)` can be simplified to `array_key_exists($_FILES, 'adjunto')` or `isset($_FILES['adjunto'])`

Answer (score 0):

Your `error_log()` call is not inside the `if` block. So it will try to use `array_keys($_FILES['adjunto'])` even if this key doesn't exist. That will return `null`, and then you'll try to use `implode(null)`.

The simple solution is to move the `error_log()` inside the `if`.

```
if (!empty($_FILES) && in_array('adjunto', array_keys($_FILES) ) ) {
    $mail->AddAttachment( $_FILES['adjunto']['tmp_name'],$_FILES['adjunto']['name'] );      
    error_log(" Files ".implode("",array_keys($_FILES)).' '.implode( array_keys($_FILES['adjunto']) ).date('Y/m/d H:i:s')."\n",3,"./adjuntos/log.log");  
}               

$mail->Send();
```